# Django: ManyToManyField not defined error

Tags: python, django, django-userena

I have been trying to edit the user profile in django-userena and everything is fine except my ManyToManyFields. I have the following models set up:

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                        verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5) 
    firstname = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=55)
    lastname = models.CharField(_('lastname'), max_length=66)
    industry = models.CharField(_('industry'), max_length=190)
    occupation = models.CharField(_('occupation'), max_length=140)
    bio = models.TextField(_('bio'))
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=10)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)
    Interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interests)
    website = models.URLField()

class Skills(models.Model):
    skillName = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Interests(models.Model):
    interestName = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

And when I sync the database I get the following errors:

```
 File "/pathtodjango/bin/app/accounts/models.py", line 17, in MyProfile
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)
NameError: name 'Skills' is not defined
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use lazy reference:

```
skills = models.ManyToManyField('Skills')
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are reffering the model class `Skills` before defining it. 
Beware that Python doesn't Function (class) hoisting as Javascript does.
So your code should be like this

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    skillName = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Interests(models.Model):
    interestName = models.CharField(max_length=140)


class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                        verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5) 
    firstname = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=55)
    lastname = models.CharField(_('lastname'), max_length=66)
    industry = models.CharField(_('industry'), max_length=190)
    occupation = models.CharField(_('occupation'), max_length=140)
    bio = models.TextField(_('bio'))
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=10)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)
    Interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interests)
    website = models.URLField()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution only works if you don't have a circular reference, otherwise the only possible solution would be @likeon 's answer